# Conditional statement like a logical fallacy in python?

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I have a binary search algorithm in python. There are  a function, named  `binary_search(array, value, low, high)`, where `array` is sorted integer array, `value` is an object that would checked the existence in the array, `low` is left bounded index (initial value `0`), and `high` is right bounded index (initial value `len(array) - 1` ). Here is my code:

```
def binary_search(array, value, low, high):
    if high < low:
        return -1
    else:
        mid = (low + high)//2
        bool_leq = array[mid] < value
        bool_geq = array[mid] > value
        print("low = %d, high = %d, mid = %d" % (low, high, mid))
        print("%s > %s is %r" % (array[mid], value, bool_geq))
        print("%s < %s is %r" % (array[mid], value, bool_leq))
        if array[mid] > value:
            return binary_search(array, value, low, mid-1)
        elif array[mid] < value:
            return binary_search(array, value, mid+1, high)
        else:
            return mid
array = []
for i in range(10):
    array.append(input())
for i in range(10):
    value = input()
    answer = binary_search(array, value, 0, 9)
    print("%d" % answer)
```

I make an input array : `[3,5,9,11,14,16,19,23,27,29]` (Note that the array length value is only 10) and the outputs are like this:

```
3
low = 0, high = 9, mid = 4
14 > 3 is False
14 < 3 is True
low = 5, high = 9, mid = 7
23 > 3 is False
23 < 3 is True
low = 8, high = 9, mid = 8
27 > 3 is False
27 < 3 is True
low = 9, high = 9, mid = 9
29 > 3 is False
29 < 3 is True
-1
5
low = 0, high = 9, mid = 4
14 > 5 is False
14 < 5 is True
low = 5, high = 9, mid = 7
23 > 5 is False
23 < 5 is True
low = 8, high = 9, mid = 8
27 > 5 is False
27 < 5 is True
low = 9, high = 9, mid = 9
29 > 5 is False
29 < 5 is True
-1
9
low = 0, high = 9, mid = 4
14 > 9 is False
14 < 9 is True
low = 5, high = 9, mid = 7
23 > 9 is False
23 < 9 is True
low = 8, high = 9, mid = 8
27 > 9 is False
27 < 9 is True
low = 9, high = 9, mid = 9
29 > 9 is False
29 < 9 is True
-1
11
low = 0, high = 9, mid = 4
14 > 11 is True
14 < 11 is False
low = 0, high = 3, mid = 1
5 > 11 is True
5 < 11 is False
low = 0, high = 0, mid = 0
3 > 11 is True
3 < 11 is False
-1
14
low = 0, high = 9, mid = 4
14 > 14 is False
14 < 14 is False
4
16
low = 0, high = 9, mid = 4
14 > 16 is False
14 < 16 is True
low = 5, high = 9, mid = 7
23 > 16 is True
23 < 16 is False
low = 5, high = 6, mid = 5
16 > 16 is False
16 < 16 is False
5
19
low = 0, high = 9, mid = 4
14 > 19 is False
14 < 19 is True
low = 5, high = 9, mid = 7
23 > 19 is True
23 < 19 is False
low = 5, high = 6, mid = 5
16 > 19 is False
16 < 19 is True
low = 6, high = 6, mid = 6
19 > 19 is False
19 < 19 is False
6
23
low = 0, high = 9, mid = 4
14 > 23 is False
14 < 23 is True
low = 5, high = 9, mid = 7
23 > 23 is False
23 < 23 is False
7
27
low = 0, high = 9, mid = 4
14 > 27 is False
14 < 27 is True
low = 5, high = 9, mid = 7
23 > 27 is False
23 < 27 is True
low = 8, high = 9, mid = 8
27 > 27 is False
27 < 27 is False
8
29
low = 0, high = 9, mid = 4
14 > 29 is False
14 < 29 is True
low = 5, high = 9, mid = 7
23 > 29 is False
23 < 29 is True
low = 8, high = 9, mid = 8
27 > 29 is False
27 < 29 is True
low = 9, high = 9, mid = 9
29 > 29 is False
29 < 29 is False
9
```

As your looking, at the left-subset from a middle array (that's `[3,5,9,11]`) aren't create an output normally than right-subset (include the middle, that's `[14,16,19,23,27,29]`). What is the mistakes?

Comment: You can use `type` to find the datatype. Just saying ;)

Answer (score 3):

This is a dead giveaway as to your problem:

```
14 < 3 is True
```

You are storing *strings* rather than numbers (lexicographically, `"14"` is less than `"3"`).

I'd suggest changing your input statement into:

```py
array.append(int(input())) # try/except might be nice as well.
```

---

And, just as a side-note: unless you're struck on a pre-3.6 version of Python, I'd be moving toward f-strings. They're a much better way to format things:

```py
# Change:
    print("Answer is %d" % answer)
# into:
    print(f"Answer is {answer}")
```

You *could* just use `print(answer)` in your specific case since that's all you're printing. This advice is more for formatting things *other* than single objects.

Comment: easier yet just `print(answer)` since there's not anything else in that string :)

Comment: Good point, @Samwise, I've modified the answer to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

You're building your array and your test values incorrectly:

```
array = []
for i in range(10):
    array.append(input())
for i in range(10):
    value = input()
    answer = binary_search(array, value, 0, 9)
    print("%d" % answer)
```

Your `array` is a list of string values, and isn't necessarily sorted correctly (especially if you're entering numeric strings and expecting them to follow numeric comparison rules).

Testing your `binary_search` function with valid (int) inputs produces the correct result, so the function itself seems fine:

```
>>> binary_search([3,5,9,11,14,16,19,23,27,29], 3, 0, 9)
low = 0, high = 9, mid = 4
14 > 3 is True
14 < 3 is False
low = 0, high = 3, mid = 1
5 > 3 is True
5 < 3 is False
low = 0, high = 0, mid = 0
3 > 3 is False
3 < 3 is False
0
```

Try using this to build your array and test values:

```
array = sorted(int(input()) for _ in range(10))
for _ in range(10):
    print(binary_search(array, int(input()), 0, 9)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are comparing are indeed integers but not in the way you may be thinking.

`str` characters in Python are encoded according to the *Unicode* standard, that unambiguously assigns a number (**code point**) to each different character.

You can easily check a character code point with `ord("char")`.

Essentially what logical operators do when the operands are `str` types is compare the actual code points of the first different characters found in the same position in both strings.

E.g.:

```
"3" > "11" == True
```

because:

```
ord("3") > ord("1") == True
```

So, since `input()` is not able to parse your input and automatically cast it into the expected data types (fortunately I'd say), you have to do it explicitly:

```
value = int(input())
```